# connection leakage with hikari CP

Tags: hikaricp, java-ee-8, connection-leaks

I have jdbs template for sql for sql statements, and use hikari connection pool, after after several calls
i took exception, i used try-with-resources, where is my mistake?(Servlet Container -Tomcat)

```
public class SimpleJdbcTemplate {

private Connection connection;
private DataSource dataSource;
private ResultSet resultSet;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
public SimpleJdbcTemplate(Connection connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
}
//private DataSourse datasource - из hikariconnectionpool

public SimpleJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public <T> List<T> query(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper, Object... args) {
    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql)){
        resultSet = null;
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
                                                         

        int position = 1;
        for (Object arg : args) {
            preparedStatement.setObject(position, arg);
            position++;
        }
        if (sql.contains("UPDATE") || sql.contains("update") ||sql.toLowerCase().contains("delete")||sql.toLowerCase().contains("insert")) {
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } else{
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            if (resultSet == null) {
                throw new SQLException("No resultsSet");
            }
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                result.add(rowMapper.mapRow(resultSet));
            }

        }
        log.info(result.toString());
        return result;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
```

Logs:

> 24-Oct-2020 13:46:16.633 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [servlets.view.MessendjerViewServlet] in context with path [/LabWork_war] threw exception
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30014ms.
> at repository.utill.SimpleJdbcTemplate.query(SimpleJdbcTemplate.java:52)
> at repository.jdbc.UserRepositoryImpl.findUserByUUID(UserRepositoryImpl.java:84)
> at service.UserService.findUser(UserService.java:71)
> at servlets.filter.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:53)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30014ms.
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:695)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:197)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:162)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:100)
> at repository.utill.SimpleJdbcTemplate.query(SimpleJdbcTemplate.java:27)
> ... 22 more

Comment: Are you able to connect to the datasource using any sql client? check connection properties once,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey i founded mistake this line is dont work correctly(try-with-resources)
(reparedStatement preparedStatement = dataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql))
i think when i try to close connection it tooks a random connection from datasource(dataSource.getConnection()),so,my connection was always open, i reformated code to this

```
public class SimpleJdbcTemplate {

DataSource dataSource;


//private DataSourse datasource - из hikariconnectionpool

public SimpleJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public <T> List<T> query(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper, Object... args) {  //TODO repair connection leak
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try {
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        resultSet = null;
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();


        int position = 1;
        for (Object arg : args) {
            preparedStatement.setObject(position, arg);
            position++;
        }
        if (sql.contains("UPDATE") || sql.contains("update") || sql.toLowerCase().contains("delete") || sql.toLowerCase().contains("insert")) {
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } else {
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            if (resultSet == null) {
                throw new SQLException("No resultsSet");
            }
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                result.add(rowMapper.mapRow(resultSet));
            }


        }
        log.info(result.toString());
        return result;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (resultSet != null) {
                resultSet.close();
                log.info("resultes finaly closed? - {}", resultSet.isClosed());
            }
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            try {

                preparedStatement.close();
                preparedStatement.close();

            } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                throwables.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {

            if (connection != null) {

                connection.close();
                connection.close();

            }
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

all worked as it should